# Howto use on bcc32 an static lib built with bcc32c

Tags: c++11, static-libraries, c++builder

I need to use a C++11 library on a bcc32 project.
The library doesn't compile with bcc32, but does with bcc32c.

I would like to prevent exposing this library on a DLL. The library compiles with bcc32c, but I wasn't able to use bcc32c static libs on bcc32 projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Static libraries are compiler-specific.  You cannot make a static lib in one compiler and use it in another compiler.  Your only options are to either wrap the static lib inside a DLL, or else change the library's code to address whatever is preventing it from compiling in bcc32.

Comment: After a painful week I concluded you're right. Not only *bcc32c* and *bcc32* are not compatible,  DLL's Classes can't be shared neither, only `extern "C"` functions. I guess that's why embarcadero gave up on borland.

Comment: @xvan: they "gave up" on the Borland compiler because its internal architecture is outdated and limited and could never be able to support C++11 and later versions of C++. It had nothing to do with lack of compatibility between the Borland and Embarcadero compilers. You can't compile a static lib in any compiler, whether it be Visual Studio or GCC or whatever, and then use it with an Embarcadero compiler, and vice versa. Sometimes you can't even use static libs across multiple versions of the *same* compiler. Like I said, static libs are specific to a particular compiler. Live with it.

Comment: They finally added a linker warning in v10.3.3 https://blogs.embarcadero.com/issues-mixing-classic-and-clang-objects-linker-warnings-improving-app-stability/

Comment: That is great and all when mixing object files from Embarcadero's classic compiler with Embarcadero's Clang compiler. But what about mixing in object files from *other vendors' compilers*? Does the new warning also work in that scenario, and is it verbose enough to report which compiler (MSVC, GCC, etc) was used to create them, or at the very least that they are non-Embarcadero object files?